# How to add submenus to a menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, menu, menu-item, submenu

My main menu is: Home | Software | Contact

I have two K2 items in 'Software' category: Soft1 and Soft2. I want to make the Soft1 and Soft2 appear as submenus in the 'Software' menu.

The Software menu is set like this:

- menu is K2
- 'Menu Item Type = Categories'
- 'Select categories = Software'

Problems:
1. The Soft1 and Soft2 submenus will appear but not under the 'Software' main menu but on the right side of the site.
2. The Soft1 and Soft2 submenus will appear all the time, no matter in which section/page I am (Home, Software, Contact).

[image]

Comment: **Beez** template doesnt support dropdown menu. Please change the template and then try

Comment: @joomler-Yep. That was the problem. Thanks. Can dropdown menu be added to Beez? The other template sucks.

Comment: Other template sucks? I can assure you that despite Protostar not being the best template in the world, it's far better than Beez3. Perhaps use a template from a 3rd party template provider. Yootheme offer a free Master Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Beez** template doesnt support dropdown menu.

You can use different templates also if the Beez template is important then you can install menu extension to work with the same template.

**Some free extensions**

1. [Maxi Menu
   CK](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/maxi-menu-ck)
2. [JMZ Dropdown Menu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/jb-dropdown-menu-for-bootstrap)

Comment: good choice ;) I mostly prefer warp framework, simply awesome